# SSRS : Can I quickly update my reports using drag and drop with .rdl files?

Tags: reporting-services

The picture below tells the story. I have a bunch of reports where the old version is on my reporting server and I have the new updated rdl files on my personal desktop. Is there a way to update all the reports at once (drag and drop or otherwise) or do I have to go into each report and save as... then navigate to the reporting server. I have about 100 reports to update in total.

[image: draganddrop]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a way to drag and drop files but if you have Visual Studio (the free community edition will work as long as you conform to the license requirements) then you can add them all to a project and then deploy them all at once.

The only other caveat is that you cannot deploy to different folders unless you setup a project for each folder.